# hide .html .php ending over htaccess RewriteEngine

Tags: apache, .htaccess

It actually worked because I only had .html files. However, it is now that I need the extension .php through a form.

I tried to copy the .htaccess rules, but the htaccess only takes the first rule.

**My try:**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.html[? ].*$"
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]
```

is there a way to hide .php as well as .html endings in the same rule, that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding:

```
Options +MultiViews
```

instead of using `mod_rewrite`.

Or, you can try this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# return 404 if .html or .php is found at the end
RewriteRule \.(?:php|html)$ - [R=404,L]

# internally rewrite to .php if that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ((?:^|\/)[^\.]+)$ $1.php [END]

# internally rewrite to .html if that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ((?:^|\/)[^\.]+)$ $1.html [END]
```

Keep in mind that `[END]` stops all mod_rewrite rules from being processed after that rule, hence stops that recursion of rewriting the rewrited url to 404.

Or you can try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} .*\.(?:php|html)[\s\?]{1}
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404,L]

# internally rewrite to .php if that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ((?:^|\/)[^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# internally rewrite to .html if that exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ((?:^|\/)[^\.]+)$ $1.html [L]
```

The second one will not stop all rewrite rules from being processed.

Comment: I got an Error 500 if i want to open any website with this entry on the .htaccess data. mod_negotiation is activated for the Multivew options.

Comment: @lumpa hmm. let me check, please wait a few seconds

Comment: @lumpa try it now. I had made a typo

Comment: i tryed but now he find no data (error 404) but they are still on the server. also if i try to open it with .html or .php dont work.

Comment: @lumpa try it now